# Youtube extractor doesn't work

Tags: c#, ios, youtube, xamarin.ios, nuget

I have a problem with the library YoutubeExtractor C#.
I develop for iOS and the problem is that when I try to create a new variable VideoDownloader Visual studio doesn't find the type.

I think that the problem is that I cannot write the file with this library!

Have someone any ideas to fix this problem??

```
        partial void UIButton220_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        IEnumerable < VideoInfo > videos= DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(url.Text);
        VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(cboResolution.TextInputMode));
        if(video.RequiresDecryption)
            DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
```

//this is not recognize by visual studio "VideoDownloader"

```
VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ildasm** to see what files the dll contains, you can find it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`. If you have installed the Visual Studio.

After analyzing the **YoutubeExtractor** nuget dll file we will see the files through the image below:

[image]

It doesn't contain a class called `VideoDownloader`. But after building the project downloaded from https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor we can find it there in the dll:

[image]

It's the problem of the third party library. You can try to use other libraries to do that. Or we need to wait until author fix that.

Comment: thank you, but I use Mac there is some similar program that I can use?